# How do I delete a cell from Excel which contains less than 3 characters? I have only one column in sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The Excel file contains only cities. I want to delete the cells which contain less than three characters.

How do I delete all the cells from Excel which contain less than 3 chars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When you are in excel press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
2. Click the "Replace" tab.
3. In the box "Find what:" enter ??. (the ammount of characters that are in the cells you're searching for)
4. The box "Replace with:", leave it empty.
5. Make sure you check the box "Match entire cell contents".
6. Then simply click the replace all button

The question mark stands for any character, so if you put in four question marks you will get only the cells with four characters.
When you put in three question marks you will only get the cells with three characters and so on.

Since you only want to delete the cells with less then 3 characters you need to do this twice.
On time with "??" (for cells with 2 characters) in the "Find What" box, and one time with "?" (for cells with 1 character) in the "Find What" box.
I hope this is what you're looking for.

[image]