# How to delete Excel rows containing cells with less than specific amount of characters in them?

Tags: excel, vba

This is  what i want to do:

[image: enter link description here]

And I tried anwsers in this thread too ;-[How do I delete a cell from Excel which contains less than 3 characters? I have only one column in sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398688/how-do-i-delete-a-cell-from-excel-which-contains-less-than-3-characters-i-have)

But I can't get it to work.

I tried some codes like these after searching for a few hours but none of them worked or maybe I am not doing it correctly:

Code 1:

```
With ActiveSheet    
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1    
        If Len(.Cells(i, "N").Value) < 6 Then    
            .Rows(i).Delete
       End If
    Next i
```

Code 2:

```
Sub M_snb()
    [N1:N100] = [if(len(N1:N100)<6,"",N1:N100))]
    Columns(14).SpecialCells(4).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Deleting rows from Excel is rather "expensive" task, thus it should be not done row-by-row, but all at once for saving time:

```
Sub RemoveRows()

    Dim rowsToDelete    As Range
    Dim cnt             As Long
    Dim currentlastRow  As Long
    Dim ws              As Worksheet
    Dim myCell          As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets(1)
    currentlastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For cnt = 1 To currentlastRow
        Set myCell = ws.Cells(cnt, 1)
        If Len(myCell.Value2) < 6 Then
            If rowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set rowsToDelete = myCell.EntireRow
            Else
                Set rowsToDelete = Union(rowsToDelete, myCell.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next cnt

    If Not rowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
        rowsToDelete.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Thus, in the code above, the `rowsToDelete` is the range with the cells, which are to be deleted. The deletion is carried out only once:

```
If Not rowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
    rowsToDelete.Delete
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will delete your rows in Column **`A`**:

```
Sub remove_rows()

    With ActiveSheet

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1

        If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) < 6 Then

            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

       End If
    Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Change `A` to any other column if you want.